# How to create a folder after clicking on a button?

Tags: 7, forms

I got a requirement like this: In the admin page there should be one create folder button, user can create a new folders as per his wish. How can I achieve this programaticaly. 
Till now I created a admin page there one button is also coming, but I am not getting how to proceed further.So please give some suggestions, thanks in advance.

 Below code I have tried.

```
  $form['create_folder'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Create folder'),
    '#submit' => 'custom_submit',
  );
function custom_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $new_folder = 'public://newfolder/';
  file_prepare_directory($new_folder, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
}
```

When I click on the submit button I got this warning
 `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in form_execute_handlers() (line 1507 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupaltest\includes\form.inc).`

Comment: What do you mean by "proceed further"? That code is correct, it'll create a folder if the web server has permissions to do so

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If don't mind may I know where can check the web server permission related to this?

Comment: The easiest way is probably through the Status Report in Drupal. It'll flag up a problem if the public files folder isn't writeable

Comment: I have edited my question and added the warning message which I am getting when i click on the button.

Comment: Hi, In the Status Report I didn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
   $form['folder_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Folder Name'),
    );
    $form['create_folder'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Create folder'),
        '#submit' => array('custom_submit'),
    );

    function custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
        $new_folder = 'public://' . trim($form_state['values']['folder_name']).'/';
        file_prepare_directory($new_folder, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
    }
```

Add validation on folder name.

Answer (score 1):

The `#submit` property takes an array of function names rather than a single string:

```
$form['create_folder'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Create folder'),
  '#submit' => array('custom_submit'),
);
```

Comment: That worked, Thank you. But my requirement was user can name the folder as per there wish. Is this possible? Because in the above code manually I am giving folder name as newfolder. So if that is possible then it would be great..